# Can't expose HTTPS in Application Gateway for EKS after following tutorial for using Lets Encrypt

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-letsencrypt-certificate-application-gateway and that all seems to be working, but I don't see how to add a HTTPS listener now to the application gateway? All is working on HTTP, but it's obviously not set up for HTTPS. I've tried to add it manually and through powershell but neither worked - manually it requires to upload an SSL certificate which I don't have, because it should be through cert-manager. What am I missing to do?

Screenshot:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Missing:** For HTTPS on this application gateway, you will need a x509 certificate and its private key.

The article which you are following states the below in point 4:
Once your staging certificate is setup successfully you can switch to a production ACME server.
So, you could follow the below article to issue an ACME certificate:
https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/http-validation/

Or generate a self-signed certificate with openssl:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls#generate-tls-certificates

> **NOTE : For production use, you should request a trusted, signed
> certificate through a provider or your own certificate authority (CA).**

Once the certificate is generated & updated, you can follow the below article to expose the service over HTTPS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-expose-service-over-http-https#expose-services-over-https

Answer (score 0):

For HTTPS you have to use the **Cert-manager** which basically manage the certificates **SSL/TLS**.

You can find the installation step here for kubernetes : https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/

Cert manager requests and manger the certificate and store it inside the Kubernetes secret and ingress refer that certificate from the secret as per need.

It's easy to install setup the cert manager.

below are the YAML example you can apply once the cert-manager installation is complete and pods are up and running.

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: cluster-issuer-name
  namespace: development
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: harsh@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: secret-name
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx-class-name
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-class-name
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: cluster-issuer-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sub.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: service-name
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sub.example.com
    secretName: secret-name
```

Replace the necessary values in above the YAML file. In ingress, you can see we are attaching the TLS part so that' secret name which will auto-generated by the cert-manager and HTTPS will be working on the domain.